# ListView "reloads" the ImageView on scroll, how do I prevent it from doing this?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, universal-image-loader

I have a listview that loads in a preview image into the row, but when I scroll down a bit and  make the row re-appear, the image seems to reload itself, as if it has to download and re-decode itself again. I'm using AQuery right now to load the image, but I've tried Novoda's Image Loader, and Nostra's Universal Image Loader, and ImageViews "reload" themselves.

Here's my simplified getView method (the image gets inserted at the bottom):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

FrameLayout postItem = (FrameLayout) convertView;
//final PostHolder holder;
if(null == postItem){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    postItem = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.column_post, parent, false);   
}

final AQuery aq = new AQuery(postItem);

    JSONObject thePost = null;
    try { 
        thePost = mPosts.getJSONObject(position).getJSONObject("data");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("errreoroer");
    }

    String postThumbnailUrl = null;
    String author = null;
    String domain = null;
    String subreddit = null;
    int votes = 0;
    int numComments = 0;
    long createdUtc = 0;

    final HashMap<String, Object> postData = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    try {

        postData.put("title", thePost.getString("title"));

        //parse thumbnail
        postThumbnailUrl = thePost.getString("thumbnail");  

        postData.put("url", thePost.getString("url"));

        postData.put("permalink", thePost.getString("permalink"));

        postData.put("is_self", thePost.getBoolean("is_self"));

        //whent it was made
        createdUtc = thePost.getLong("created_utc");

        //author
        author = thePost.getString("author");

        subreddit = thePost.getString("subreddit");

        domain = thePost.getString("domain");

        votes = thePost.getInt("ups") - thePost.getInt("downs");

        //num_comments
        numComments = thePost.getInt("num_comments");

    } catch (Exception e) {}    


    //gets the direct url to the image
    mSmartContent.getDirectMedia((String)postData.get("url"), new Callbacks() {

        @Override
        public void callback(Object obj) {

            Bundle cData = (Bundle)obj;

            if (cData.getString("type") == "pic") {

                aq.id(R.id.imagePreview).visibility(View.VISIBLE).image((String)cData.getString("url"));


            } else {

                aq.id(R.id.imagePreview).visibility(View.GONE);

            }


        }



    });


    return postItem;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Universal Image downloader and Novoda's image loader is ***not reloading*** image again from web but fetching images from cache if its already downloaded once.

Comment: I understand they aren't doing that, I'm just wondering why the images take to long to load back in from cache when they are less than a megabyte in size.

Comment: If you look at these libraries, I would bet that they have some form of memory usage limit before they start recycling bitmaps. They might have APIs that allow you to up these limits, but otherwise this would be expected behaviour. Look at your LogCat output and they'll be some messages about garbage collection.

Comment: I'll check that out, if that's the case is there a way, to change the settings that the universal image loader uses throughout different areas in the app?

Comment: You might consider not using one MB images in a list view and down-scale them for this purpose.

Comment: You should consider using ViewHolder pattern along with ImageLoader from https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0):

Without keeping the images in memory, they will have to be reloaded (whether from some cache or from the network).

You can avoid the appearance of this by pre-loading (binding) your views before they appear in the viewport, similar to how the ViewPager loads pages that are off-screen, but it's unrelated to the image loaders.